# Dockercompose run command on mounted directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create an editing environment for my project - I want to run `poetry update` on the code repository in the container when the container starts instead of manually having to do it.

When running `docker-compose build editor-environment` but obviously if we haven't run `docker-compose up editor-environment` the `/code` directory has not been mounted. How could I accomplish something like this?

**Docker-Compose.yml**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  editor-environment:
    build:
      dockerfile: env_docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    tty: true
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10.4-slim-buster
RUN pip install poetry
RUN cd /code --> throws error, can't cd to /code
RUN poetry updates
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh -c"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

Comment: Can you use a lighter-weight environment, maybe Poetry in a normal virtual environment without Docker?  Since the code and library dependencies are normally built into an immutable Docker image, it can be tricky to use this as an actual development environment.

Comment: Try to use `"$(pwd)"` instead of dot in your volumes section; in windows also afaik absolute paths are used. See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/06_bind_mounts/).

Comment: And [bind mounts docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-top-level-element).

Comment: @DavidMaze I would prefer running this locally, but my IT department doesn't make it easy for me to change my local env variables etc. Pretty cumbersome, but this is my workaround